# pandoc doesn't accept `<` pre-text conventions from apacite

Tags: pandoc, apacite

I'd like to use pandoc to convert a long `.tex` to `.docx`. For reasons of `and` vs. `&` usage in in-text citations, I chose to use `apacite` over `natbib`. By convention, apacite has users place 'pre-text' in `<>` brackets, such that `\cite<see>[]{citation}` becomes (see Citation, year). Pandoc returns an error in for these cases.

```
> pandoc -s MWE.tex -o test.docx
Error at "source" (line 13, column 47):
unexpected <
```

How to I help pandoc interpret apacite's pretext convention? Is there a way I can write pretext information with in apacite to produce the same result without `<>`? Or is pandoc only compatible with `natbib`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Biblo.bib}
@article{aka,
  title={Fingerspelling formulae},
  author={Aka, Carol T}, journal={SLR},
  volume={83}, pages={126--132}, year={1985}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Some citations}
apacite lets me \citeA{aka}, \cite{aka}, \cite<also>[]{aka} \\
but pandoc doesn't like the $<$ in \cite<e.g.,>[]{aka}

\section{Ref list}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Biblo}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: You can use `apacite` with `natbib` citation commands by using the `[natbibapa]` package option. This shouldn't affect the rendering of the output.

Comment: You could ask on the pandoc mailing list. Perhaps they can add a filter to get around the problem. But on the whole I would say you should avoid packages which introduce unusual syntax when you want to convert a document automatically in some other format. That's always a source for troubles.